# Are there any tools for converting Cython back to regular Python (pyx2py)?

Tags: python, cython

I'd really like to use Cython more, but I'd like the ability to convert it back into regular Python 3.x code at a moment's notice if for some reason I want to stop using Cython.

Are there any tools already written that do this?

Comment: How much have your written?  What style?  Just a few `cpdef's`?  or full blown rewrites using low level iteration?

Comment: Have you seen [pure Python mode](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html)?

Comment: I've hardly written anything at all in Cython; just a few short programs over the course of a few years. I'm not wanting to convert stuff I've already written, though. I have programs written in regular Python that I'm tempted to manually optimize for Cython (to speed them up), but only if I can convert them back without going over a novel's worth of code manually to reverse it (since I'll want to continue the programming after converting to Cython).

Comment: I hadn't seen pure Python mode. :) @DavidW

Comment: Do you expect to write whole programs with Cython, or just key, time crucial functions?  If you rewrite a bottleneck function in Cython, then you'll have both.  The whole point to using Cython is to continue to use Python for the major development.