# Convert Cython code to Python code

Tags: python, cython

I have to pickle some data on one machine and unpickle it on another with a different architecture.

My data contains datatypes from some modules that were written in Cython. Is there any (automated) way to convert the Cython modules into a standard Python module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757033/are-there-any-tools-for-converting-cython-back-to-regular-python-pyx2py

Comment: @hpaulj not very helpfull

Comment: So how is your question different?  You haven't specified whether you are talking about the `.pyx` files or the `.so` ones.  I'm not even sure what you mean by `datatypes`, especially as it applies to pickling.  Just be happy that you got a comment; the question could be closed for lack of a `mcve`, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or just not being clear.

Comment: The answer is still "No, there is not an automated way of converting Cython to Python". Why not just compile the Cython module on the other machine?